# Linux scrollwheel "Jump back" when I scroll

Tags: linux, x11, mouse, scrolling

I have a very frustrating problem, I THINK the real problem is bad hardware, but I have had the problem with multiple brands (including logitech) so I assume the windows driver fix this and thus no reason to spend money on proper hardware.

Using

```
xev|grep "state 0x10"
```

to track events on mouse gives this when scrolling down on wheel.
Do anyone have a fix for this problem, I figure it should just ignore any 0x10 if there is no 0x1010

```
state 0x1010, button 5, same_screen YES
state 0x10, button 4, same_screen YES
state 0x10, button 5, same_screen YES
state 0x1010, button 5, same_screen YES
state 0x10, button 5, same_screen YES
state 0x1010, button 5, same_screen YES
state 0x10, button 4, same_screen YES
state 0x10, button 5, same_screen YES
state 0x1010, button 5, same_screen YES
state 0x10, button 5, same_screen YES
state 0x1010, button 5, same_screen YES
state 0x10, button 4, same_screen YES
state 0x10, button 5, same_screen YES
state 0x1010, button 5, same_screen YES
state 0x10, button 5, same_screen YES
state 0x1010, button 5, same_screen YES
state 0x10, button 4, same_screen YES
state 0x10, button 5, same_screen YES
state 0x1010, button 5, same_screen YES
state 0x10, button 5, same_screen YES
state 0x1010, button 5, same_screen YES
state 0x10, button 5, same_screen YES
```

Have anyone a solution

Edit:
It turned out to be a matter of cleaning the encoder like described in this video. After doing that the mouse worked perfect again
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEVoNRp6v9E
Also I THINK later versions of the X11 mousedrivers handle this (and windows does for sure). Should be a matter of just accepting one event every 10ms or something like that.

Comment: I have the same problem, though it's scroll speed dependent, wondering if it could be a sampling/polling rate issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try cleaning your mouse scroll wheel. Modern mice use optic tracking for the mouse scroll wheel, so if it's really dirty a clean should fix it.

Comment: Thanks, I actually have already solved it.
Cleaning it was sort of the solution. I had to follow this instruction to get it working.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEVoNRp6v9E